# Pandas (0.16.2) Show 3 Rows of Dataframe

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to limit the output of the pandas dataframe to the first 3 rows.  However I get a summary of all 500000 data points.  When I run this without specifying "Time [s]" as the index it works properly and I only get 3 rows of data.  I'm running Pandas 0.16.2 and Python 3.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from sys import platform as _platform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default') # Make the graphs a bit prettier
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 5)

shot1 = "C:\\Users\ELEC-LAB_1\Documents\GitHub\Black Powder\BlackPowder_Shot-1.csv"
shot1_data = pd.read_csv(shot1, parse_dates=['Time [s]'], index_col='Time [s]') # Read the data using the time as the index.
shot1_data[:3]
```

Time [s] CH 1 [psi] CH 2 [psi] CH 3 [psi] CH 4 [psi] CH 5 [psi] CH 6 [psi] CH 7 [psi] CH 8 [psi] CH 9 [psi] CH 10 [psi] CH 16 [V]

-0.200000
-0.018311 -0.054932 -0.012207 -0.054932 -0.006104 -0.048828 -0.030518 -0.018311 0.030518 -0.018311 0.011597

-0.199998
0.006104 0.109863 0.048828 0.048828 -0.018311 -0.054932 0.042725 0.054932 -0.042725 0.024414 0.010986

-0.199996
0.012207 -0.042725 0.061035 -0.097656 0.067139 0.006104 -0.054932 -0.067139 -0.097656 -0.134277 0.010986

-0.199994
0.012207 -0.006104 -0.079346 0.036621 -0.036621 0.042725 0.006104 0.067139 0.012207 -0.042725 0.011597

-0.199992
0.006104 0.067139 0.091553 0.091553 0.024414 0.012207 0.097656 -0.030518 -0.024414 0.061035 0.010986

-0.199990
0.036621 0.006104 0.061035 0.109863 0.073242 0.067139 0.109863 -0.054932 0.158691 0.000000 0.011597

500000 rows × 11 columns

Comment: `shot1_data.head(3)`

Comment: It looks like what you're doing is setting the index to a datetimeindex but then trying to select the first three rows using values that don't exist anymore in your index for slicing: `shot1_data[:3]` if you did `shot1_data.head(3)` or `shot1_data.iloc[:3]` then it would do what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to slice a df which has a `datetimeindex` using integer values that are not valid which is why you get the full df.

Example:

```
In [34]:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2015,1,1), end=dt.datetime(2015,1,10)))
df[:3]

Out[34]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2015-01-01 00:00:00, 2015-01-02 00:00:00, 2015-01-03 00:00:00, 2015-01-04 00:00:00, 2015-01-05 00:00:00, 2015-01-06 00:00:00, 2015-01-07 00:00:00]
```

If you used `head` or `iloc[:3]` then you get the desired result:

```
In [35]:
df.head(3)

Out[35]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2015-01-01 00:00:00, 2015-01-02 00:00:00, 2015-01-03 00:00:00]

In [36]:    
df.iloc[:3]

Out[36]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2015-01-01 00:00:00, 2015-01-02 00:00:00, 2015-01-03 00:00:00]
```

That is why when you don't pass param `index_col='Time [s]'` to `read_csv` your line of code works as a default `int64` index is created for you.

Comment: So does an index have to be an integer or do datetimeindex's have to be an integer?

Comment: index can be anything, ints, floats, strings, datetimes etc. but what you did without realising is to try to slice using ints but what's it's trying to do is look for int values in your index which don't exist hence why you got the entire df, `head` and `iloc` don't care about the index dtype so they work as you expect

Comment: If I used 'shot1_data[:-0.199996]' it would show only the first 3 rows?

Comment: No, your index is datetimeindex not a float, if you did `shot1_data.index[:3]` you will see the actual values of your index and see what I mean

Comment: Answered my own question.  So whatever you index by in a dataframe you must use that index system for slicing be it strings A,B,C, integers 0,1,2, or floats 0.23, 0.24, 0.25.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is correct where the indexing uses the labels, if you use `iloc` this is integer based so it doesn't care about dtype, if my answer resolved your question please remember to accept it so the question doesn't stay unanswered, there will be an empty tick mark at the top left of my answer